# Trying to convert a string to Int

Tags: c#, string, int

Im trying to convert a string to int in visual studio, but whenever i do it cant seem to pick up the thing im trying to refrence it to.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void points1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = Int32.Parse(textbox1.Text);
        resultBox.Text = 
    }
}
```

}

I really cant find anything, since solutions online didnt seem to work at all.

Comment: *it cant seem to pick up the thing im trying to refrence it to* could you explain this differently? Having trouble understanding what you mean.

Comment: Furthermore "I really cant find anything, since solutions online didnt seem to work at all." is unclear. On what solution do you concern?

Comment: your x has the converted int though... what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `int.TryParse`: *try* parsing `textbox1.Text` into `int`, on success put `textbox1.Text` itself as a result; on fail, let's write, say, `"?"`:

```
int x;

resultBox.Text = int.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out x) ? textbox1.Text : "?";
```

Comment: yes,it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try This ;

```
    int x = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
```

or this ;

```
    int x = 0;

    Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out x);
```